# File upload not submitting

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am setting up a file upload server. I get error 5 (upload failed for an unknown reason) when I test it.

I am using w3schools' guide on setting up php based file upload. I have suspicions that the issue is with $target_dir.

Here is some of my code:

```
$target_dir = "u/files/" . time() . rand(000000000000, 999999999999) . "/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
mkdir($target_dir, 0700);
$FileTypeToUpload = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded. Your file has been uploaded <a href='u/?file=" . $target_file . "'>here</a>.";
} else {
    echo "Error 5<br>";
}
```

I want a new folder to be created and the file uploaded in it. But instead it gives error 5.

With errors enabled I am getting:

> Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in
> /home/u502270334/domains/ppyazi.com/public_html/ppshare/upload.php on
> line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in
> /home/u502270334/domains/ppyazi.com/public_html/ppshare/upload.php on
> line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in
> /home/u502270334/domains/ppyazi.com/public_html/ppshare/upload.php on
> line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in
> /home/u502270334/domains/ppyazi.com/public_html/ppshare/upload.php on
> line 39 Error 5

Comment: Make sure you have enabled error reporting (`ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);`). You need to make sure that your `mkdir` call actually worked before doing anything else.

Comment: Would that just go in that file? I haven't set up php.ini, my host does it for me.

Comment: Yes, you may add that to your file.

Comment: If `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` is not even set, then you likely did not perform a _correct_ file upload in the first place. So show us the _uploading_ part.

Comment: It uses js to upload```<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">https://ppyazi.com/starfiles/u/</span>
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
</div>
<progress id="progressBar" role="progressbar" value="0" max="100" style="width:100%;"></progress>
<h3 id="status"></h3>
<p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>```

Comment: Also, I updated it so ```$_FILES["fileToUpload"]``` is now ```$_FILES["file1"]```